# Most compatible way of escaping embedded strings for other commands

Tags: bash, perl, escaping, echo, zsh

I'm currently using the following solutions.

## For literals `'string'`

```
variable="'"$(echo -E "$variable" | perl -pe "s/'/'\"'\"'/g;")"'"
```

## For literals `"string"`

```
variable='"'$(echo -E "$variable" | perl -pe 's/(?=[\\"])/\\/g;')'"'
```

- I believe Perl is available in almost all environments.
- I'm afraid `echo -E` is NOT available in some environments...

Do you know better ones?

> I know we can execute with temporary environment variables.
>
> ```
> NAME=VALUE command
> ```
>
> However, some programs do not provide any ways for accessing them.

#### AppleScript example

[image]

---

## EDIT

I found that AppleScript can handle argument with `on run argv ~ end run` syntax.

[image]

Comment: Please provide an example of how you intend a program to use `variable`. What you appear to be trying to do now is just plain wrong; embedded quotes are part of the value, not syntactic quotes to protect special characters.

Comment: AppleScript example: `osascript -e "log $variable"`; Any characters can be correctly displayed in my environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes are part of the AppleScript syntax, so should be kept separate from the actual data.

```
osascript -e "log \"$variable\""
```

or

```
osascript -e "log '$variable'"
```

Comment: This is not actually a good solution; if `variable` contains the kind of quotes you are using to wrap it, your dynamically constructed program will not be correct. The *right* answer is to pass `$variable` as an argument: `osascript -e "..." "$variable"`, but I don't know AppleScript well enough to provide a valid example.